# Mocking JPA repository in Spock integration tests

Tags: java, groovy, spring-boot, mocking, spock

Spring seems to load beans randomly in my test context.

I have following repository classes for `User`:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findOneByExternalId(Long externalId);

    Optional<User> findOneById(Long id);

}
```

and it's test equivalent:

```
@Primary
@Repository(value = "userRepository")
public interface TestUserRepository extends UserRepository {

    Long TEST_CORRECT_USER_ID = 1L;
    Long TEST_INCORRECT_USER_ID = 2L;

    @Override
    default User findOneByExternalId(Long externalId) {
        return getTestUser(externalId);
    }

    @Override
    default Optional<User> findOneById(Long id) {
        return ofNullable(getTestUser(id));
    }

    default User getTestUser(Long id) {
        if (TEST_CORRECT_USER_ID.equals(id)) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setExternalId(id);
            user.setDevices(emptyList());
            user.setId(id);
            return user;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and two more for `Device`:

```
@Repository
public interface DeviceRepository extends JpaRepository<Device, Long> {

    Optional<Device> findOneByDeviceId(String deviceId);

    Optional<Device> findOneByDeviceIdAndToken(String deviceId, String token);

}
```

test equivalent:

```
@Primary
@Repository(value = "deviceRepository")
public interface TestDeviceRepository extends DeviceRepository {

    @Override
    default <S extends Device> S save(S device) {
        return device;
    }

}
```

the test below is passing for the `UserRepository`, but not for the `DeviceRepository`:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestDeviceRepository, TestUserRepository])
class IntegrationContextSpecTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext

    @Unroll("Bean #bean should be instance of #clazz")
    def "should initialize test beans instead of normal beans"() {
        expect:
        clazz.isAssignableFrom(applicationContext.getBean(bean).
                                       getClass())

        where:
        bean             | clazz
        UserRepository   | TestUserRepository
        DeviceRepository | TestDeviceRepository
    }

}
```

What might be the cause of it? I iterated over `applicationContext` contents and it clearly says that my `UserRepository` bean have a name `userRepository` and my `DeviceRepository` have a name `deviceRepository`.

Here's the output from test:

```
Condition not satisfied:

clazz.isAssignableFrom(applicationContext.getBean(bean).getClass())
|     |                |                  |       |     |
|     false            |                  |       |     class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143
|                      |                  |       interface com.example.repository.DeviceRepository
|                      |                  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository@10e4cf09
|                      org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@7dc51783: startup date [Sun Nov 27 22:09:16 CET 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@56aaaecd
interface com.example.test.integration.mock.TestDeviceRepository
```

Comment: How it's failing? What is the message?

Comment: How about remove the `@Primary` annotation?

Comment: @Opal it says that `DeviceRepository` bean is not an instance of `TestDeviceRepository`. I thought it's obvious, sorry! In the error there is information about how `DeviceRepository`'s class is a proxy (as expected, it's JPA magic after all), so nothing especially useful.

Comment: @LipingHuang nope, didn't help. Also, I've made another test that uses only `TestUserRepository` and... it fails randomly too. The issue seems to be related only to JPA repositories, as other Beans (ordinary classes like `RestTemplate`, not magical interfaces) are correctly overridden in the context.

Comment: I tried adding names to normal repository classes like `@Repository(value = "userRepository")` and `@Repository(value = "deviceRepository")` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you please replace `S` generic type with `Device`?

Comment: @Opal tried that already, doesn't work. `@Override Device save(Device device) { return device; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solutions are sometimes the most difficult to think of. I admit that I was overthinking the problem too much.

All I had to do is use `@Profile` annotation like:

```
@Repository
@Profile("!test")
public interface DeviceRepository extends JpaRepository<Device, Long> { 
    /* ... implementation... */ 
}
```

and in the test class

```
@Repository
@Profile("test")
public interface TestDeviceRepository extends DeviceRepository { 
    /* ... implementation... */ 
}
```

And now all my tests are passing!